# XSLT 2.0 sort using letters and numbers

Tags: xslt

I have a sequence of strings that look like this:

B5 C10 C8 D11 D13 D3 D7 D9 E12 E8

I did the <xsl:perform-sort and <xsl:sort, based on the default data-type="text" and it's working correctly. But I would like to further sort so that after the letter the values are sorted numerically:

B5 C8 C10 D3 D7 D9 D11 D13 E8 E12

Any suggestions on how to do that? Thanks!

Edited to add my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="pns1" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="distinct-values($combo1/*:pin/*:pkg[$pos]/*:pn/@n)">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="pns2" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="$pns1">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
     </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:message select="$pns2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="strings" select="('D13', 'B5', 'C10', 'E12', 'C8', 'D11', 'D3', 'E8', 'D7', 'D9')" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$strings">
            <xsl:sort select="substring(., 1, 1)"/>
            <xsl:sort select="substring(., 2)" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>B5 C8 C10 D3 D7 D9 D11 D13 E8 E12</result>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's working for me, I'll try to integrate it into my code

Comment: I successfully integrated it into my code - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Saxon allows you a parameter `alphanumeric="yes"` on a collation URI, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/localization/unicode-collation-algorithm/ so e.g.

```
'B5 C10 C8 D11 D13 D3 D7 D9 E12 E8'  
=> tokenize('\s+') 
=> sort('http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?alphanumeric=yes')
```

gives

```
B5 C8 C10 D3 D7 D9 D11 D13 E8 E12
```

.

Online fiddle with Saxon XQuery (but XPath/XSLT support it the same): https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9Xvk.

Using `numeric=yes;fallback=yes` might even give better compatibility between the various Saxon editions (HE, PE, EE) and platforms (Java, .NET):

```
'B5 C10 C8 D11 D13 D3 D7 D9 E12 E8'  
=> tokenize('\s+') 
=> sort('http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes;fallback=yes')
```

or [even SaxonJS](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22data%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%7B.%20%3D%3E%20tokenize%28%27%5Cs%2B%27%29%20%3D%3E%20sort%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2013%2Fcollation%2FUCA%3Fnumeric%3Dyes%3Bfallback%3Dyes%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cdata%3EB5%20C10%20C8%20D11%20D13%20D3%20D7%20D9%20E12%20E8%3C%2Fdata%3E&input-type=XML).